# Divide two special value in same column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i want two divide two values from a column as below:

[image]

actually i want divide blocked call by call attempt and result in percentage.

I used below code and answer is ok:

select 
round((cast(100*(select count (event) as EventCount from dbo.['New ST$'] where event = 'Blocked Call') as float))
     / (cast((select count (event) as EventCount from dbo.['New ST$'] where event = 'Call Attempt') as float)),3) 
as 'BCR(%)'

Thanks @GMB

Comment: Adding text sample data instead of images would be much helpful. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Kindly tag properly. `MySQL and SQL- Server` are different. And don't post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline queries:

```
SELECT 
    100.00 * (SELECT eventCount FROM mytable WHERE event = 'Blocked Call')
        / (SELECT eventCount FROM mytable WHERE event = 'Call Attempt')
```

Or using aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    100.00 * MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'Blocked Call' THEN eventCount END)
        / MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'Call Attempt' THEN eventCount END)
FROM mytable
```

---

**Edit**

It appears that the data that you showned is already the result of an aggregated query. You can get you expected results by querying directly the initial table like:

```
SELECT 
    100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Blocked Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Call Attempt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mytable
WHERE event IN ('Blocked Call', 'Call Attempt')
```

Comment: thanks, actually i made the table by below code:   select distinct (event), count(event) as EventCount from dbo.['New ST$'] group by Event order by 1  so your code not working as it can't know EventCount

Comment: @Ebrahim: you should have said that in the first place... OK I edited my answer with a query that you can run directly on your original table (the intermediate step that you added is not needed).

Comment: Dear GMB, yes, thanks a lot for your great support.